# "At the time" or "In the time"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammar, prepositions, word-difference

I'm writting something like this "A help at/in the most difficult time/moment", and I don't know what is correct, *at* or *in*... and the same thing with *time* or *moment*, I don't know what word I should use.

Answer (score 3):

All four iterations could be considered correct and synonymous:

- She was a help at the most difficult time
- She was a help at the most difficult moment
- She was a help in the most difficult time
- She was a help in the most difficult moment

Without further context, it's hard to say for sure which one I would recommend.

---

As a footnote, I'd probably change *the* to something more specific (but, again, without more context, it's hard to say for sure what would constitute an improvement):

- She was a help in *my* most difficult time
- She was a help at *this* most difficult moment

Comment: It's about a past time, like "this was a help in/at the most difficult moment/time (years ago)"

Comment: Past or present doesn't much matter.  What matters more is relative duration.  "At" works better for something brief.  "In" works better for something that lasts.  "A moment" is probably shorter than a stretch of years, but not necessarily if in comparison to centuries or eons.  This involves a subjective judgment about relative duration (how long the help lasted, how long the difficult period lasted, and just what feels like a long duration *to you*) so none of the four options are wrong.

Comment: @GaryB - I agree about duration. If a firefighter rescues me from a burning building, I'm being helped _at_ a most difficult time. If an insurance agent is helping me get resettled after a house fire, I'm being helped _in_ a most difficult time. But learners should know: these are just vague generalities and there is plenty of wiggle room.